# How to fix "Call to a member function execute() on string" on my function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm modifying a Wordpress API witch is currently getting learnpress course and lessons infos from the database using leanrpress functions only. I need to modify the API to get the scores from the newly implemented plugin h5p, therefor i need to make a new function to access the Database and get the scores from the right table, then put then into an array with the according  lesson. The array here is only an exemple i'm using to see if i can get the datas, ut i'm stuck with the error

> "Call to a member function execute() on string"

when i try and run it on postman. Could someone lighten me on this issue please ?

```
function ilp_api_get_progress_by_mail($data){
    $mail=$_GET['mail']; //$data->get_param["mail"];
    $course_id=$_GET['course'];
    global $wpdb;

    $user=get_user_by("email",$mail);
    if($user !== false){
        $lp_user=learn_press_get_user( $user->ID );

        if($course_id==NULL){
            $all_courses=ilp_api_get_all_courses($data);
        }else{
            $all_courses=array('courses' => array(array('id' => intval($course_id))));
        }

        $progress=array();
        $i=0;
        if($all_courses!=NULL && $all_courses['courses']!=null){
            foreach($all_courses['courses'] as $course){
                if($lp_user->has_enrolled_course($course['id'])){
                    $lp_course=learn_press_get_course( $course['id'] );
                    $course_data       = $lp_user->get_course_data($course['id']);
                    $course_results    = $course_data->get_results( false );
                    $progress[$i]=array(
                        'id' => $course['id'],
                        'name' => $lp_course->get_title(), //$course['name'],
                        'condition' => $lp_course->get_passing_condition(),
                        'completed' => $course_results['completed_items'],
                        'total' => $course_results['count_items'],
                        'progress' => absint( $course_results['completed_items'] / $course_results['count_items'] * 100 ),
                        'permalink' => $lp_course->get_permalink(),
                    );
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        $result = array(
            'userfound' => true,
            'user_id' => $user->ID,
            'connect' => get_h5p_grades(),
            'courses_progress' => $progress,
            'course_id' => $all_courses,
        );

     function get_h5p_grades(){
    global $wpdb;

    $ID = 1;
    $ID_use = 1;


    $result = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT score FROM mci_h5p_results WHERE id = %d AND user_id = %d', $ID, $ID_use);
    $result->execute();
    $donnees = $result->fetch();
    return $donnees;
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation `wpdb::prepare` method returns 
>  Sanitized query string, if there is a query to prepare.

Comment: Yes but i doubt this is the problem with my code here since prepare and execute works in tandem, or maybe i'm missing something basic but important here ?

Comment: I'm sorry i wasn't thinking right when i wrote the previous comment, yes it returns a sanitized string but it's because i'm working with Wordpress and that's pretty much the problem. I was confused (and still am) with the normal PDO and the Wordpress modifications.